# Making a loop for an integral equation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a bunch of equations. (All the equations are a function of temperature now, but I will set a certain temperature for this calculation.) These will be constants in the last differential equation (dlscaleDtO2[temp_]).

I need to update the initial value (lscale) with the value obtained by integrating the last equation by a short period of time. The obtained value should keep updated during a loop calculation until the time reaches a certain value.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I found many loop functions in the documentation, but it didn't help me a lot. If you have any examples similar to this, please let me know. Thank you.

```
Jo2scale[temp_] = Π02scale[temp]*(Po2s[temp]/lscale);

dlscaleDtO2[temp_] = 
  2/3*Vsio2*Jo2scale[temp] - 
   Vsio2*(JSiOvO2[temp] + 
      JSiO2v[temp]);(*Scale growth rate when only O2 exists*)
```

Comment: It sounds a bit like you are trying to solve a differential equation, in which case [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)/[`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) could help. Also, can you provide a specific example of the type of equations you're working with? It's a bit hard to judge from the text what exactly you're after.

Comment: @LukasLang I added my code. It looks very complicated, but the last differential equation should be integrated by a short period of time and the obtained value will be used as a new 'lscale'. This calculation will be repeated.

Comment: @YiJeCho Thank you for adding the code. Now there's perhaps too much detail :-) You may more readily attract attention if you could reduce your problem to a smaller example that can be completely run from the code included in your post.

Comment: You may want to consider using standard values for constants when available, e.g., `R = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["PhysicalConstant", "MolarGasConstant"]["Value"]]` or `MAr = QuantityMagnitude[Entity["Element", "Argon"]["MolarMass"]]`